# What if I store less characters in Char data type then its specified length?

Tags: mysql, sql, char

I know that ***char*** data type stores fixed length strings. What if I store a string of 5 characters in a field of datatype ***char(10)***? How would SQL store/ manage that data?

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I tried. the documentation says that the data would be right padded with spaces. But when I checked the length, it gave me 5.

Comment: Probably because the spaces are padded at the end, trailing spaces are ignored. Try `SELECT LEN(Column + 'x') - 1` to include trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

They are right-padded with 5 spaces.

[As the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) say:

> When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.

```markdown
| Value  | CHAR(4) | Storage Required |
|--------|---------|------------------|
| ''     | '    '  | 4 bytes          |
| 'ab'   | 'ab  '  | 4 bytes          |
| 'abcd' | 'abcd'  | 4 bytes          |
```